# Do not draw thumbnails in fine-uploader - or dont throw error

Tags: logging, console, thumbnails, fine-uploader

Is it possible to configure fine-uploader that it not draws thumbnails.
I use another drag-area and the area used for fineuploader is hidden.
My target is, do avoid the error message in the console "Problem drawing thumbnail!".
Or is it possible to not throw this error?

Answer (score 1):

As the [styling feature page](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/styling.html) says, you can omit almost any portion of your template. In your case, omit the qq-thumbnail-selector element to prevent fine uploader from drawing any thumbnails.